# Payment URI support

Tags: source-code-documentation, payment-integration

According to the Wolfram Warptangent, [Point Release 1 notes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.1), the new release will `add Monero payment URI support to the wallet library`

What is the definition and purpose of payment URI support?

Is there any source code documentation that explains how this new feature can be utilized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monero: scheme allows sending payment information. The main piece of data that's included is an address. Optionally, you can also include payment id, a comment, the name of address owner, and an amount.

This is meant to be used in cases where you are expecting a particular payment, and send this URI (either directly, or via QR code) to a client, who will use it to setup a transaction.

See http://monero.wikia.com/wiki/URI_formatting for more information about the rules for this URI scheme.